# CSS media query only triggers for one div

Tags: html, css, media-queries

My media query only triggers for the .gridContainer class. No changes happen when the condition is met for '.container' and 'p'. font-size and padding-bottom values don't change but all the attributes in gridContainer do. I don't think the order matters as long as the media query is at the bottom of the css file but please correct me if I'm wrong.
I'm sorry if my HTML looks sloppy, I think there are a few mistakes that I need to sort out so any suggestions about the code are also appreciated.

```css
.container{
    padding-left:2%;
    padding-right:2%;
    padding-bottom:0.5%;
}
.gridContainer{
    display:grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: auto;
    grid-template-areas: 
    "tearooms tearooms"
    "bedbreakfast bedbreakfast"
    "store craft"
    "post news";
    margin-top: 4%;
    margin-left: 15%;
    margin-right: 15%;
    grid-row-gap: 5%;
    grid-column-gap: 3%;
}
.mainimg{
    width: 100%;
}
main{
    margin-left: 4%;
    margin-right: 4%;
}
body{
    background-color: #bfcfb8;
    font-family: 'Gill Sans MT';
    padding-bottom: 20%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    min-height: 100vh;
}
.maintext{
    position: absolute;
    padding-left: 68%;
    top: 2%;
    right:7%;
    text-align: right;
    font-size: 1.5vw;
    font-family: Palatino Linotype;
}
.maincontainer {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
  }
.image{
    display:block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    /*height: 60%;*/
    width: 34%;
}
.cafe{
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    float:right;
    border-radius: 0px 12px 12px 0px;
    padding-left: 3%;
}
.view{
    width: 45%;
    object-fit: cover;
    float:right;
    padding-right: 4%;
    padding-left: 3%;
    padding-bottom: 2%;
    padding-top: 2%;
}
.bedandbreakfast{
    width: 45%;
    object-fit: cover;
    float:right;
    padding-bottom: 2%;
    padding-top: 2%;
}
p{
    font-size: 130%;
    padding-left: 3%;
    padding-right: 3%;
}
h1{
    font-size: 150%;
    margin-bottom: 3%;
    margin-top: 4%;
    padding-left: 3%
}
h2{
    font-size: 150%;
    margin-bottom: 3%;
    margin-top: 4%;
    padding-left: 3%
}
header{
    /*grid-area: header;*/
    color: #3f5e36;
    background-color: #a3c296;
}
nav{
    /*grid-area: nav;*/
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 1%;
    padding-right: 2%;
    padding-left: 2%;
    font-size: 70%;
}
nav li {
    position: relative;
    margin-right: 5%;
}
#footer{
    background-color: #a3c296;
    text-align: center;
    color: #3f5e36;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    padding-left: 2%;
    padding-right: 2%;
    height: 8%;
    margin-top: auto;
}
#tearooms{
    grid-area: tearooms;
    /*margin-left: 15px;*/
    background-color: #f8fcd3;
    border-radius: 12px;    
}
#tearoomtxt{
    margin-right: 50%;
    padding-bottom: 3%;
}
#news{
    grid-area: news;
    background-color: #db72f3;
    border-radius: 12px;
    color: white;
}
#bedbreakfast{
    grid-area: bedbreakfast;
    background-color: #cf91a4;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 12px;
}
#store{
    grid-area: store;
    background-color: #f4a963;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 12px;
}
#craft{
    grid-area: craft;
    background-color: #6e93e4;
    border-radius: 12px;
    color: white;
}
#post{
    grid-area: post;
    background-color: #ed4f64;
    border-radius: 12px;
    color: white;
}
ul{
    display: inline;
}
a:link {
    color:#385230;
    background-color: transparent;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
a:visited {
  color: #385230;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
  color: #6e8b61;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:active {
  color: #57a733;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.bedFlex {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin: 11px;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 906px) {
    .container {
        padding-bottom:1.5%;
    }
    .gridContainer {
        margin-left: 4%;
        margin-right: 4%;
        grid-row-gap: 3%;
        grid-column-gap: 2%;
        margin-top: 2%;
    }
    p {
        font-size: 90%;
    }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="eng">
<link href="Chollerton tearooms.css" rel="stylesheet">

<head>
    <meta charset = "utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Chollerton tea rooms</title>
</head>
<style>
    ul#menu li {
        display:inline;
    }
</style>
<body>
    <div class = "container" style = "font-size:1.8em">
        <header>
            <img src="logo.png" class="image">
            <nav>
                <ul id="menu" style="list-style-type: none; ">
                    <li><a style="text-decoration:none" href="Chollerton tearooms.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a style="text-decoration:none" href="Find out more.php">Find out more</a></li>
                    <li><a style="text-decoration:none" href="View requests.php">View requests</a></li>
                    <li><a style="text-decoration:none" href="#">Credits</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>
    </div>
    <div class="maincontainer">
        <main>
            <img src="mainimage.jpg" class="mainimg">
            <div class="maintext">
                <h1>Explore Chollerton<br>tea rooms</h1>
                <p1><br><br>Welcome to Chollerton tea rooms. We are an independent company based in the hamlet of Chollerton. With a wide range of facilities; fresh, specialised tea and locally sourced hand made treats, we invite you to join our community and enjoy what we have to offer.</p1>
            </div>
        </main>
    </div>

    <div class = "gridContainer">
        <!--<section class = "flexParent">-->
        <div id="tearooms">
            <img class="cafe" src="cafe.jpg">
            <div id="tearoomtxt">
            <h2><strong>Tea rooms</strong></h2>
            <p>At Chollerton tea rooms we pride ourselves on our range of different teas. From a traditional british cup of tea to our highly sought after herbal green tea crafted by our skilled staff using Sri Lankan tea leaves, south east asian spices and our special ingredient! Our wood finished cafe area takes you into the heart of Asia where the exotic tea leaves were freshly picked by our fair trade tea farmers. We are open every day from 8am and we stop serving at 5pm. </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="bedbreakfast">
            <section class = "bedFlex">
            <h2><strong>Bed & Breakfast</strong></h2>
            <p>We are proud to offer bed and breakfast to our fabulous customers in the heart of Chollerton's best local walking routes. With our award winning full English breakfast delivered to your comfy bed upon request and views attracting people all over the country, our bed and breakfast is the perfect getaway experience. All our rooms have an en-suite and free wifi is included.</p>
            <img class="view" src="view.jpg">
            <img class="bedandbreakfast" src="bedandbreakfast.jpg">
            </section>
        </div>
        <div id ="store">
            <h2>Village store</h2>
            <p>Make your way to our store where fresh, locally sourced produce can be purchased in support of the village farming community. Souveniers can also be found at our store to serve as a momento for the experience you had with us. Open 7 days a week, our staff will be more than happy to help you choose some of our lovely products from 7am to 6pm.</p>
        </div>
        <div id ="craft">
            <h2>Craft shop</h2>
            <p>Don't forget to check out our arts and crafts shop if you decide you're feeling creative. All manner of art supplies can be found here we guarantee you will leave happy. We have professionals on site from 10am to 4pm to supervise and teach in a range of activities from kite making to landscape paintings.</p>
        </div>
        <div id ="post">
            <h2>Post office</h2>
            <p> In case you require postal services we have a post office at your disposal sharing the village store opening times.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="news">
            <h2>News</h2>
            <p> - Open hedgehog habitat building class every Saturday 10am.<br> - Exotic tea taster session 3pm every day. <br> - New weekend bike hire - please contact for more information.</p>
        </div>
        <!--</section>-->
    </div>
</body>
<!--
<div id="footer">
<footer>
    Chollerton tea rooms &copy;<br>By Kieran Ashton
</footer>
</div>
-->


</html>
```

Comment: Just tested the code and the `.container` and `p` rules in the media query seem to apply for me. In a viewport less than `906px` wide, the text in `<p>` elements are smaller and `.container` elements have less bottom padding. Is this what you were expecting?

Comment: The question is a bit vague, I see your media queries are applied and you have a typo using `<p1>` tag while you should type only `<p>`  for paragraph, so it will be best if you described what your media queries do (as far as  I see, all they do is just adjusting some margins and paddings and they are applied when I checked on  the dev tools

Comment: I see the same as the other commenters; the media query works for me. On a side note, it's a bit strange to use so many % values all over the place. The convention is usually to use rem/em with regard to spacing and sizes.